# Electronic Number Lock - Digital Electronic Systems

Tags: digital-logic, actuator, binary

I've been set a Uni assignment to design an electronic number lock using a Keypad, an Electronic Control Unit and an Electromechanical Locking Actuator.  It's to be based on a 4-bit binary codeword.

Unfortunately Digital Electronics is by far my weakest subject and so I'm not particularly sure where to begin with this.  Any help will be massively appreciated.

Regards,

Connor

Comment: You're physically building it or just designing on paper? This is a typical introductory problem in the area of *state machines*. You might want to look up that term to get started.

Comment: Ahhh, memories.  I made this circuit for tech college using discrete logic in about 1992.  What would today be a weekend's work in an MCU or FPGA took me about 10 weeks of designing and testing, it was the first complex logic that I ever designed.  Have fun...

Comment: A 4-bit binary codeword?  That's only one digit.  Perhaps you mean a 4-digit codeword.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to give you a full circuit here, since we don't do that for someone doing homework problems.  But hopefully I will give you enough clues to get started.

I am going to assume you meant a 4-digit input sequence as I asked in my comment.

I also assume you need to design this using discrete logic, and not use a microcontroller, since the latter would make the project rather trivial.

As already mentioned in a comment, you will need to build a state machine (SM) to keep track of where you are in the digit input process (i.e. state 0 is initial, state 1 is one correct digit entered, state 2 is two correct digits entered etc.  The SM can be build using a counter such as the [74HCT4017](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4017.pdf).

I suggest you encode the output of the four switches into BCD (binary coded decimal) using a chip like the [74HCT147](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT147_CNV.pdf).  Then using a 4-bit comparator such as the [74HCT85](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT85_CNV.pdf), you can compare the switch pressed with a preset code, and if equal, advance the SM to the next state.

When the SM reaches state 4 (all four digits matched), then operate the locking actuator.  The code can be either hardwired, or set using DIP switches for each digit like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/206-4/CT2064-ND/20748).

If during the entering of digits, an incorrect digit is entered, then you will want to reset the SM to state 0.  You might also want to include a Clear button the does the same thing.  Depending on security, you may also want to include an LED to indicate the SM is in state 0 and ready to accept the first digit.